# How to build maccore from source?

Tags: open-source

I want to build the latest [maccore](https://github.com/mono/maccore) from source.

Problem: I have searched everywhere but can't find any build instructions.
Question: How to build maccore?

I am a Mac newbie but intimate with UNIX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put [monomac](http://github.com/mono/monomac) at the same directory level as `maccore`
2. Go to monomac directory
3. Run `make`